# polling envelope status in docusign using webhooks and c#

Tags: c#, docusignapi, webhooks

I was reading about polling to get the status changes for a Docusign envelope. The article mentioned Webhooks, but gave very few code examples, and the examples were in Python and PHP.

I would like to find out how to use Webhooks in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you check out the [DocuSign Webhook - C# Recipe](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-csharp) repository on GitHub, which provides sample code that shows how to use webhooks (DocuSign Connect) with C#.

Comment: I believe the issue is mainly within the question, not the answer. The question is asking examples of webhooks, not providing code or help for fixing code.